# I am trying to install Ubuntu OS and I encounter an input/output error while installing the system

Tags: error-handling, ubuntu-16.04

[On the fourth last line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1VDJ.jpg)

I tried to install Ubuntu OS on my laptop and my internet went down so I got an error. I have tried formatting the SSD but it persists giving error every time I boot up and try a fresh install. I have also redone the Iso file download.